# CoordinatorLayout - snap not working if I scroll header

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I have `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout` with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `NestedScrollView`.
Here layout structure *(unimportant attributes skipped)*:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

             <ImageView
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            <!-- header content with toolbar -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways">

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <!-- where 
            string "appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" is
            android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior
        -->

        <!-- main content -->   
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If I scroll this page by touching `NestedScrollView` it's ok - `snap` flag works correctly. But if I scroll by touching header (AppBarLayout) `snap` not working - header stops in middle state.

Is it known issue? Or maybe I put wrong scroll flags to my layout? How can I fix it?